# Who would convert Nebuzardan?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, churban-destruction, maseches-gitin, anti-semitism

In Gemara [Gittin 57b](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin_57b.1) we find a story about Nebuzardan "taking revenge" for the murder of Zechariah Hanavi.

To make a long story short, after he literally slaughters thousands of Jewish men, women and children, he runs away and converts to Judaism.

My question is who and why would anyone convert such a man to Judaism?

Comment: Perhaps the beis din that converted him didn't know who he was or maybe they were aware of the teshuva he had done

Comment: "_A Divine Voice emerged and said: Rabbi Ḥanina ben Teradyon and the executioner are destined for the life of the World-to-Come_. [Upon hearing this], _Rabbi_ [Yehuda HaNasi] _wept and said: There is_ [one who] _acquires his_ [share in the] _World_ [-to-Come] _in one moment_, [such as the executioner], _and there is_ [one who] _acquires his_ [share in the] _World_ [-to-Come only] _after many years of toil_, [such as Rabbi Ḥanina ben Teradyon]" ([Avodah Zarah 18a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Avodah_Zarah.18a.13?lang=bi&lang2=en)).

Answer (score 2):

Even if someone has a bad past, the Torah almost always allowed the, to convert. (Unless you”re an amelakei). Anyways, this just comes to show Hashem’s infinite kindness and pity for sincere teshuvah

Comment: Can you prove your assertion that an Amaleki cannot convert? A strong counterpoint can be made from the fact that the (great-)grandchildren of Haman converted!